# How to do group by substring in Eclipselink?

Tags: group-by, eclipselink, jpql

I'm trying to group the store by store country and see how many stores there are in each country. The store country happens to be the first 2 characters of the store's code. That means if the store code is "US000010", the country is "US"

My entity object:

```
...
public class Store {
    @column(name = "code")
    private String code;
    ...    
}
```

My JPQL is:

```
  SELECT substring(s.code, 0, 2),
         count(s) 
    FROM Store s 
GROUP BY substring(s.code, 0, 2)
```

This keeps throwing me `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`, which I suspect is due to the JPQL above that is converted to

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CODE, ?, ?), COUNT(CODE) FROM Store GROUP BY SUBSTR(CODE, ?, ?)
```

Excluding other alternatives like creating a view or using native query, is there any way I perform a group by substring in Eclipselink using JPQL?

Comment: Did you try specifying an identifier for your substring function result?  "select substring(s.code, 0, 2) as mystring, count(s) from Store s group by mystring"?

Comment: Doesn't work. Still getting same error. The JPQL is still converted to the same sql it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem grouping by a `TO_CHAR` function. The solution I found is ExclipseLink specific, and it was just to set a hint on the query: `query.setHint(QueryHints.BIND_PARAMETERS, HintValues.FALSE);`.

Put this code before executing the query and it will not use parameters, but replace the values directly on the SQL string sent to the JDBC driver